# Compute the determinant of the matrix and find a basis of its column space

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The given matrix is 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

To obtain the determinant, I use Guass method on this 4x4 matrix until I get a matrix of a form where there are 1 zero in front of the second row, 2 zeros in front of the third row and 3 zeros in front of the fourth row.

1) do p1+p2, -p1+p3 and -p1+p4 and you get the matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

2) then do -2p2+p3,-p2+p4 and you get the final matrix as:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

My answer:
The determinant also known as the product of the diagonal is zero because
$1 * 1 * 2 * 0 = 0$

The column space is $|S| = \{c_1s_1 + \dots + c_ns_n \mid c_1,\dots,c_m \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } s_1,\dots, s_n \in S\}$

http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d86/warnexus/basis_zps4b301a1b.png

I do not know what value are the constants of my column space. Should I keep it general like the above?

Comment: To find a basis, you can look at the pivots of your row reduced matrix. The corresponding columns of your original matrix form a basis for the column space.

Comment: When you mean pivot do you mean leading variables? the leading variables are 1,1,2. I am pretty sure there is no leading variable for the fourth row of the row reduced matrix since the fourth row are all zeroes.

Comment: That is what I mean.

Comment: finding the basis by looking at the leading ones, my basis elements are 1 -1 1 1 and 1 0 3 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "pivots" of your final matrix---that is, in each row, pick out the first non-zero entry, if one exists, and write down what column number it's in (i.e. column 1, column 3, etc.). Since your original matrix has the same number of columns as your final matrix, each column number you wrote down specifies a column of your original matrix. These columns then form a basis for the column space.

Let's go through your specific problem. The pivots in rows 1, 2, and 3 of your final matrix occur in columns 1, 2, and 3, respectively. However, row 4 is entirely 0's, so it doesn't have any pivots. Therefore, we can completely ignore row 4. Thus, the only column numbers we write down are 1, 2, and 3. Picking out columns 1, 2, and 3 of our original matrix, we find that
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\3\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\4\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
forms a basis for the column space.

Comment: Oh! I see I thought it had to be leading ones for some reason. I had to look at leading variables from my row reduced matrix and see which column corresponds with the original matrix instead. I forgot to list the last basis element due to that...